# A little question about unit test in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-unittest

I'm following the https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-app-testing and was stuck on step 6.

In function in file **test/favorites_test.dart** , the test fails if I changed the **i+=2** to **i++** and I don't know why.  If the total items is less than 6, it can pass too. Why the number is so important in test.

It is a simple app, when tap the close button, just delete from list
[image]

//test/favorites_test.dart

```dart
Widget createFavoritesScreen() => ChangeNotifierProvider<Favorites>(
      create: (context) {
        favoritesList = Favorites();
        return favoritesList;
      },
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: FavoritesPage(),
      ),
    );

void addItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
    favoritesList.add(i);
  }
}

void main() {
  group('Favorites Page Widget Tests', () {
    testWidgets('Test if ListView shows up', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(createFavoritesScreen());
      addItems();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byType(ListView), findsOneWidget);
    });

    testWidgets('Testing Remove Button', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(createFavoritesScreen());
      addItems();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      var totalItems = tester.widgetList(find.byIcon(Icons.close)).length;
      await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.close).first);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(tester.widgetList(find.byIcon(Icons.close)).length,
          lessThan(totalItems));
      expect(find.text('Removed from favorites.'), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Because `i+=2` increments by two, and `i++` increments by one. They're not the same thing. Also, we don't follow links off-site to get information needed for a question. All relevant content has to be here, in the question itself. You've not explained what *step 6* is or included the function's code.

Comment: @KenWhite Hi, thanks for your reply. I do know the `i+=2 increments by two, and i++ increments by one. `. I have edited the original post. The app is simple that when tap the close button, just delete from the least. So that I don't know the reason why the test fail.

Comment: Where does the test fail? Can you include the logs in your post?

Comment: @ValentinVignal Hi, I have found the solution already, even I don't know why. Thanks  again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

In `testWidgets`, the test runs in size **(2400,1800)** according to `tester.view.physicalSize`. (I don't know why the test page is not shown fully)

After `tester.view.physicalSize = Size(10000, 10000)`, the test passed.

Don't forget to call `tester.view.resetPhysicalSize()` or it will affect the following widget tests.